# Mlogit in R: Data shape

Tags: r, mixed-models, mlogit

I want to run a Multinominal Mixed Model Analysis using the r Package mlogit.

Unfortunately somethings is wrong with my data structure, as r can not seem to find the data (error below). Child is Choiceid and CASE is subject ID. I also want to add a group variable as I have a btw Subject factor group, meaning that the participants were separated in 3 different groups with a slightly different choice scenario.

Does anyone have an idea how to add that to the model? I'm still a beginner to choice modeling an r in general. I would want to consider the individual level and the group level in my model.

```
> mixdata <- dfidx(df_model2, choice = "Choice", varying = 4:19, sep = "_",idx = list(c("chid", "CASE")), idnames = c("chid", "alt"))
> head(mixdata, 10)

~~~ indexes ~~~~
indexes:  1, 1, 2 
> 
> #radomisierte effekte bestimmen
> rdm <- c(ArtHausarzt = "n",  ArtBeratung = "n", ArtEhrenamt = "n", ArtSelbsthilfe  = "n", SettingGruppe = "n")

> #modellschätzung
> ml_mix <-mlogit(formula = Choice ~Art + Setting,  data = mixdata, rpar = rdm,  panel = TRUE, method = "nr")
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'type here
```

My data has the following structure:

| CASE | Group | Choice | Art_1 | Art_2 | Format_1 | Format 2 | ... | chid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | Psychotherpie | Selbsthilfe | Einzeln | Gruppe | ... | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Beratung | Hausarzt | Gruppe | Gruppe | ... | 2 |

I tried to use the vignette as a template: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c5.mxl.html

The columns in varying are correct so are all the names of the variables.